# Wouldn't it be nice if we can also bookmark the answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am talking about the star in the right side of questions. It is a method to keep track of important questions. However for me, it is a list of important solutions for those problems that I probably will face again.

The point is, sometimes there are lots of answers, some of them are outdated/wrong/not working for me. I prefer to bookmark those answer. With current bookmark method, I can only bookmark the question...

Would it not be nice if we can also bookmark the answer?

Comment: Yes, that would be nice. Sometimes the answer is more important than the question!

Comment: All posts -- including answers -- have a share button in the lower left which provides you with a link to the specific post. You could bookmark that in, e.g., your browser.

Comment: @Null: True, but have a 'Favorite Answers' list on the  TeX.SX web site would be much better, in my point of view!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't oppose a 'Favorite Answers' feature; I'm just suggesting a workaround as long as such a feature doesn't exist.

Comment: @Null: True as well. As long there's no better way your proposition is good, of course!

Comment: Has been asked previously, see [Is there any way to favorite/bookmark an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569) and some linked questions.

Comment: didn't know it is already asked.

Comment: @Woeitg: No worries: Sometimes questions on Meta.SX are quite hidden

Comment: Was also discussed on this Meta Stackexchange question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star (and, sadly, though it had 205 upvotes, declined)

Comment: Why this request was declined in the past?